# How to select for an empty datetime in Dynamics AX 2009

Tags: axapta

I have a table with a field name "StartDateTime" of type "DateTime". I want to do a query where those fields are null.

In the table browser, I see these fields as "       00:00:00", where non-empty fields are like "2010-09-14 00:00:00".

I tried using without success:

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(smmActivities)).addRange(fieldNum(smmActivities,DataAreaId)).
                value(strFmt('(%1!=%2)',
                fieldStr(smmActivities, StartDateTime),
                date2strxpp(datenull())));
```

---

`date2strxpp(datenull())` returns 1900-01-01. So I presumes that's why it's not working. I thinkI need to find a date2strxpp that return '00:00:00' in a datetime format. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than that:

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(smmActivities)).addRange(fieldNum(smmActivities,StartDateTime)).value(SysQuery::valueEmptyString());
```

Or in a user range: "" (two quotes)